# Не получается UPDATE с вложенным запросом SELECT

Tags: update, mysql, sql-server, select, sql

Здравсвуйте! Возникла необходимость обновить в базе данные по определенным критериям, разовый запрос выполнить получается с введенными параметрами ручками (вариант 1):

```
UPDATE test.user.mail
SET ExecAuditorID = 'параметр1'
WHERE ID = 'параметр2'
```

Так как мне надо поправить около 600000 строк, нужно написать такой UPDATE, который бы все параметры выгрузил был и их вставил в UPDATE.
Написал следующий скрипт (2):

```
UPDATE test.user.mail
SET ExecAuditorID = (SELECT AuditorID FROM test.user.mail)
WHERE ExecAuditorID = 'параметр1'
```

То есть мне надо заменить все записи, где ExecAuditorID = 'параметр1' на ExecAuditorID = (SELECT AuditorID FROM test.user.mail).
Я вкурсе, что нельзя делать одновременно два запроса к одной таблице. Но мне кажется, это как-то можно сделать. Кстати, выпала ошибка:

> subquery returns more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=.... т.д.

По идее, запрос отрабатывает, но я так понял из этой ошибки, что нужен какой-то цикл типа loop в Oracle:)

Ладно, что-то покрутил и пришёл к идее сделать такой вариант (3):

```
UPDATE test.user.mail
SET ExecAuditorID = t.AuditorID
FROM (SELECT AuditorID FROM test.user.mail WHERE ExecAuditorID = 'параметр1') AS t
WHERE AuditorID = t.AuditorID
```

И тут я наконец получил то, чего добивался, ту самую ошибку, где говорится нельзя делать два запроса к одной таблице, хотя вроде, используя алиасы, все должно отрабатывать. Сама ошибка:

> Ambiguous column name 'AuditorID'

Чуть не забыл, пробовал до вышеописанного скрипта такой вариант (4):

```
UPDATE test.user.mail
SET ExecAuditorID = t.AuditorID
FROM (SELECT AuditorID FROM test.user.mail WHERE ExecAuditorID = 'параметр1') AS t
```

И он отработал, он вставил во все записи заместо t.AuditorID это 'параметр1', как так получилось, до сих пор не понял. По сути, ничего не должно было произойти.

Просьба помочь разобраться, как так написать скриптец, чтобы все отработало согласно условию из третьего скрипта. Заранее спасибо за любые наводки.

Comment:     Ambiguous column name 'AuditorID'
Говорит только о том, что сервер не знает, который из AuditorID вы имеете в виду. Это не есть запрет на использование таблицы дважды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил задачу так:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.EXecAuditorID = t2.CREATORID
FROM LDMAIL AS t1
JOIN LDMAIL AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.EXecAuditorID = 'параметр1'
WHERE t1.CREATORID = 'параметр2'
```

Теория здесь:[ТЕОРИЯ UPDATE MS SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177523.aspx)